# Android for MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, android, mono, monodevelop

I am new to Ubuntu. Before, I used VS in Windows and develop applications with C#. Now, I want to start developing Android applications.
after search ... I install MonoDevelop.I start to read documents for this.on [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation) page, I understand should install Mono for android, But I can't find this for Ubuntu.there are only for Windows and Mac.
I am really starter! please help me and clean what dose it mean..!
if i have mistake, show me How to start develop Android Applications whit MonoDevelop and C#.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono for Android development is only supported on Windows and Mac OS X. It's not currently supported on any distribution of Linux.

Comment: are you sure? is there any other solution for this?

Comment: @AmirHossein, the fact is clear if you check Xamarin download page, http://xamarin.com/trial, and their doc page, http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation

Comment: ok,I know. is there another way for develop android application in Ubuntu with C# ?