# Monodevelop + Linux and Android Xamarin developement

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.mac

Is it possible to develop a portable Xamarin mobile (Android) application with MonoDevelop on Linux?

I'm using Linux Mint, I have installed MonoDevelop with the guides [MonoDevelop linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBeDm.png) and [MonoDevelop Ubuntu-Debian](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).
After installing, I have expected, when creating a project, to find out a project type  similar to "Xamarin Android Application" or something.

The only project type mentioning cross-platform + Xamarin is this:
[image: project creation]

The guides on Xamarin site only applies to Xamarin Studio. I am lost, is there something broken in my installation or it is simply impossible to use MonoDevelop to develop Xamarin for mobile Android applications (and I totally misunderstood)?

In case, can you point me to a guide or resource about developing Xamarin portable mobile apps with MonoDevelop?

PS: There is one Stack Overflow question with last comment of year 2012, and, since then, lot things have changed: Xamarin merge with NET.foundation, the open source release of [Xamarin SDK](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/). 
Clearly I have misunderstood about Linux support availability. I have thought the question should be re-formulated. I hope this match the policies.

Comment: No, you can't build Xamarin Android apps on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android for MonoDevelop on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065513/android-for-monodevelop-on-ubuntu)

Comment: That question covers the same problem, the last comment is about 4 years ago: Since then few things have happened: xamarin merge with NET.foundation, the opensource release of xamarin SDK. Clearly I have misunderstood about Linux support availability. I have thought the question should be re-formulated. I hope this match the policies. I also wanted to improve things by providing more details and other sub-questions.

Comment: @FabianoTarlao It is possible... There was someone on Twitter that had it `Xamarin.Android` compiling on Linux as he was the first to do it outside of the Xamarin devs. The Xamarin Studio Android Add-Ins are **not** open source and thus he was using Android Studio for axml editing, VSCode for C# editing along with a bunch of build/deploy scripts to glue it together. Not sure what his debug experience was like. You should ask on the gitter channel

Comment: Thanks I'll check for the sake curiosity. I'm looking to something reliable-no-hussle and ready to use. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, Xamarin Android will be available in Linux , but ETA is still unclear.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android

Comment: Technically it is now available for linux, but with zero support and zero tooling/IDE integration. So it pretty much useless to anyone.